# How to write to a character special device?

Tags: linux, devices, usb-drive, usb-device, character-special-files

Due to a broken `udev` setup on a machine from which I'm trying to rescue data (see [this post of mine](https://superuser.com/questions/1268868/can-i-save-these-documents-on-a-dying-machine-from-oblivion)) I'm trying to write to a "character special" device corresponding to a USB flash drive, but am encountering difficulty.

What I would expect is that (with root permissions) I could do this:

```
echo "test 123" > /dev/bus/usb/001/031
```

But I get

```
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

What's going on? How can I write to a character device?

***P.S.***: this is of interest specifically because the block devices I would normally expect (`/dev/sdb`, stuff in `/dev/block`) aren't being created for some reason. Yet I noticed that a character device does get created when I insert a USB drive (and removed when I remove it). If I could find some way to write to that device I could save myself a lot of trouble transferring data slowly over audio cables (which is my current best approach).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are "raw USB" devices. Using them requires several USB-specific `ioctl()` functions: just writing raw data into them from the shell is unlikely to accomplish much at all. The data would have to be formatted into valid USB packets first, and the `ioctl()` functions used to establish connection to the right USB endpoint within that device.

And since we're talking about a USB storage device, the procedure would be even more complicated: withing those USB packets, there should be one of six possible storage command sets. In practice, the overwhelmingly most common command set is the "SCSI transparent" command set - a SCSI protocol wrapped into USB.

As a result, you would first have to learn how to write onto a disk device using `/dev/sg*` devices, by crafting your own SCSI command packets. Once you achieved that, you could add USB-specific wrappers onto that procedure, and only then you might be able to write raw blocks onto a USB storage device using those `/dev/bus/usb/<busnum>/<devnum>` devices.

In most cases, using raw USB `ioctl()`s is extremely tedious unless you need something very specific: most programmers needing raw USB access will use `libusb` or some other library (like `libftdi` for hardware-developer-level access to FTDI USB-to-serial converter chips) to handle the base mechanics of USB for them. In short, you would have to already be a pretty well established USB I/O programmer to successfully use raw USB storage device in a rescue situation such as yours.

Having said that, your other post looks like you've had to pull off a truly epic data rescue operation. For that, I respect your achievement... but I also hope you've learned something about the importance of backups.

Comment: Followup question: were I able to create the block device file for a USB drive, could I write directly to that? Or does that still require special handling like this character device?

Comment: If the usb-storage kernel module was loaded and the problem was just a failure of udev to create the device node, then yes; you could use the `mknod` command to create the device node and then write to it with `dd` or perhaps even mount it. The usb-storage module will normally do all the "special handling" required for you. But if the module cannot be loaded, then creating the device file would do nothing at all: any attempts to write into that device would just result in an "unknown device" error message.

Comment: It appears that the `usb-storage` module is not loaded, and I get an I/O error when I try to load it. No luck.